# I'm a bit confused re: how Eclipse MAT displays "Unreachable" objects. I'm reading two customer dumps and want to follow the unreachable objects

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm reading two customer heapdumps and want to follow the unreachable objects, but I only see the message, unreachable when viewing the objects in the Dominator tree. I cannot find anyway to display the Unreachable Histogram or follow the objects.

I’m using Eclipse MAT 1.50. [The link states](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_analyse_unreachable_objects):

> Memory Analyzer version 1.1 has a preference page option to select
>   keep_unreachable_objects.

I do see objects marked unreachable, but I cannot follow them. Also, I don’t see **Java Basics > Unreachable Objects Histogram**  I’ve set the option under **Window > Preferences > Memory Analyzer > keep unreachable objects**.  I did restart MAT after changing the setting.

For example, here’s one object –

```
Class Name                                                | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.catalina.Session[740] @ 0x7cf807688 Unreachable|        2,976 |         2,976
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's a link which shows the menu item - http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/mimes/threads_overview.png

My questions:

- How do I enable Unreachable Objects Histogram?
- Should I be able to follow the object chain or am I misinterpreting what I should see when looking at Unreachable?

I realize a bug exists, but looking for breadcrumbs

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

The "Keep unreachable objects" preference should be applied on loading the heap, it shouldn't require a restart or any more configuration than that.

Yes, the **Java Basics > Unreachable Objects Histogram** option does seem to be missing, but there's a link to access it on the Overview tab.

[image]

"Keep unreachable objects" does seem to be **buggy**: it seems to work much more often when set to FALSE than to TRUE. So if you don't get the right result, clear all the dump's temporary files leaving just the `.hprof`, set the preference to FALSE and try reloading/recalculating.

To be honest, the Histogram isn't particularly useful, but this is what it looks like (Mat 1.4.0).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I'll run through your suggestions and update the question

Answer (score 0):

Basically, followed Andrew's suggestion setting keep_unreachable_objects to false, restarted MAT. The Leak Suspects chart looked very different showing a large object we analyzed finding a potential coding bug. The larger retained heap for an object helped me to focus on the issue. Yes, we saw some of the same data again when reviewing the dump, but now I can start working on a use case to isolate the code causing the bug.

Also, the Overview screen showed Unreachable objects, but provided few details to the issue.

Hopefully, the above makes some sense.

Thanks, Andrew for the help.